# view in playfrmework not recompiling in production

Tags: playframework

Have to adjust a html display text in production. Got my copy on test server and made the change in my view Display.html

stopped and started tomcat/apache. did not see my changes reflected when i refreshed my browser.

Is there a way that i can perform this or do i have to recompile entire project with change to the view and then to place it on production? Or do i make a change to a java file on my test machine and then restart tomcat/apache so that would force entire app to recompile?

Answer (score 1):

Views are precompiled in production. On a standalone play installation you can use the play precompile command (with play 1.2.x), but I guess that with tomcat you have to rebuild your war